# Is it valid to publish an Android library with javax.inject as a dependency?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, android-lint, javax-inject

I'm writing an Android library that depends on a JVM library that depends on `javax.inject`. The default Android linter appears to disallow `javax.inject` as a (transitive) dependency for most Android libraries, but it whitelists it for Dagger and Guice. Can I write an Android library with a `javax.inject` dependency, and if so, what considerations do I need to know about?

I'm writing both of these libraries: a pure-JVM library, i.e. a JAR, and an Android library, i.e. an AAR, that depend on the JVM library.

I would like my JVM library to support Dagger. The library is simple enough that I don't think providing a `@Component` or anything is necessary; just the `@Inject` constructor should do the trick.

So, not wanting to burden non-Dagger consumers with any extra dexing etc., and thinking myself clever, I included just `javax.inject`, not Dagger itself, in the JVM library's build.gradle file:

```
implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
```

Thus Dagger users can just inject the JVM library's object as they see fit, and non-Dagger users never know the difference (because the `javax.inject` library is just a few annotations). In a test app with Dagger, this seems to work as expected.

But! In the Android library that consumes the JVM library (and provides some Android-related conveniences for it), running `lint` causes an error: "Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.inject." Since I knew that Dagger already uses this library I was confused, so I googled the lint error and found that the Android linter [specifically whitelists Dagger](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/InvalidPackageDetector.java#268).

Why is `javax.inject` disallowed by the default linter for all other libraries? Are Dagger and Guice doing something extra-special to make sure `javax.inject` is available, or can I just ignore the error?